# Copy identification data to next line(s) using perl regex

Tags: regex, perl

I have many large data files in text format where rows are like:

```
UserID#1                                data from interaction 1
                                        data from interaction 2
                                        data from interaction 3
UserID#2                                data from interaction 1
                                        data from interaction 2
```

and so on. Each user ID may have from 1 or more rows associated to it. The data always starts on character 41. It's hard for me to process this data algorithmically without first getting it to look like:

```
UserID#1                                data from interaction 1
UserID#1                                data from interaction 2
UserID#1                                data from interaction 3
UserID#2                                data from interaction 1
UserID#2                                data from interaction 2
```

Is there some nice perl regex I could execute to just make this happen? I've been reading about capture groups, but I just can't get this to work. I want to capture the first 40 characters of a line that doesn't begin with white space, and then use that to replace the subsequent lines' first 40 characters until reaching a line that also does not begin with white space. And then repeat.

---

Update: Ultimately, one of the regex expressions I was trying worked. But I learned regex in vim, and I see now that which characters need escaping, and how to reference capture groups, is not the same in vim as it is with perl.

Comment: Please show your efforts first to solve your problem?

Comment: @AruneshSingh I've been trying things like `perl -pi -e 's/(^\S.{39})(.*\n)^\s{40}(.*\n)/$1$2$1$3/g' data.txt` but all that I try has no effect.

Comment: If it's too much to work this out, what is the general topic in the world of regexp that I need to read up on, to handle multiple lines better?

Comment: @alex.jordan It's not that it's too much work to help. It's that debugging questions ("why doesn't this work?") need to include a specific problem and reproducible code. I think you'll find that people are very willing to help when your question contains those two things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be tempting to turn to regular expressions as the *magic bullet* that will solve all problems that "normal" programming cannot. However, they are not all-powerful and should be used carefully and in concert with Perl's standard syntax to provide solutions to situations for which they are well-suited. Understanding which situations those are comes with practice, but I don't believe that this is one of them

It is simple to parse each line of data in a standard `while` loop. To get a user ID to use for those lines that don't provide one, you can simply declare a variable outside the loop that keeps track of the *last* non-blank user ID that has been encountered, and use that for those lines that start with blanks

This program demonstrates the idea. I prefer [`unpack`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html) for processing fixed-width fields, but you can do this with `substr` or a regex pattern if you prefer

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Data::Dump;

my $curr_user;

while ( <DATA> ) {
    my ($user, $data) = unpack 'A40 A*';
    $curr_user = $user if $user;

    dd [ $curr_user, $data ];
}

__DATA__
UserID#1                                data from interaction 1
                                        data from interaction 2
                                        data from interaction 3
UserID#2                                data from interaction 1
                                        data from interaction 2
```

#### output

```
["UserID#1", "data from interaction 1"]
["UserID#1", "data from interaction 2"]
["UserID#1", "data from interaction 3"]
["UserID#2", "data from interaction 1"]
["UserID#2", "data from interaction 2"]
```

Comment: Thanks, and also for the wisdom about regex. Looks like I don't have `Data::Dump`, but I'll try add it/find it in the morning.

Comment: @alex.jordan: It is a successor to [Data::Dumper](http://metacpan.org/module/Data::Dumper) written by *Gisle Aas*, the author of the excellent [LWP](http://metacpan.org/module/LWP) suite. I find it far preferable to its predecessor but it's not a core module so you will need to install it. I've used it only to expose the data that my code has extracted, so you can `use Data::Dumper` and `print Dumper [ $curr_user, $data ]`, or just `print qq{"$curr_user", "$data"\n}` instead, but in your final program you will just go ahead and use those values instead of printing them